# How to properly mount routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, jwt, postman

I'm designing REST API and I already implemented most of endpoints but when I test them with postman I get this error message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /api/test</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I will share my files below
this is server file

```
const express = require("express");
const makeStoppable = require("stoppable");
const http = require("http");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const Users = require("./services/userService");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const authenticateToken = require("./services/authMiddleware");
const routes = require("../routes");
const app = express();

const server = makeStoppable(http.createServer(app));
app.use("/assets", express.static(__dirname + "/assets"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set(
  "views",
  "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/simple-to-do-aplication-master - Copy (2)/views"
);
const SECRET_KEY = "Secret Key";
const validation = [
  check("email").isEmail().withMessage("Invalid email"),
  check("password")
    .isLength({ min: 6 })
    .withMessage("Password must be at least 6 characters long"),
  check("firstName").notEmpty().withMessage("First name is required"),
  check("lastName").notEmpty().withMessage("Last name is required"),
];

// Middleware to check JWT token

app.use("/", routes());
// User registration route
app.post("/api/register", validation, (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
  // Check if a user with the same email already exists
  const existingUser = Users.getUserByEmail(email);
  if (existingUser) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "User with this email already exists" });
  }

  // Create a new user object
  const newUser = {
    email,
    password,
    firstName,
    lastName,
  };

  // Add the new user to the users list
  Users.addUser(newUser);

  // Return a success response
  res.status(200).json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
});
app.post("/api/login", validation, (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Check if a user with the provided email exists
  const existingUser = Users.getUserByEmail(email);
  if (!existingUser) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
  }

  // Check if the provided password matches the stored password
  if (existingUser.password !== password) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
  }

  // If the user exists and the password is correct, create a JWT token
  const token = jwt.sign({ email: existingUser.email }, SECRET_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "24h", // Token will expire in 1 hour
  });
  // Return the token as a response

  res.status(200).json({ token });
});

module.exports = () => {
  const stopServer = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      server.stop(resolve);
    });
  };

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    server.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Express server is listening on http://localhost:3000");
      resolve(stopServer);
    });
  });
};
```

this is index route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const tasksService = require("../src/services/taskService");

const doneRoute = require("./done");
const apiTasks = require("./apiTasks");
module.exports = (params) => {
  router.use("/done", doneRoute(params));
  router.use("/api/tasks", apiTasks(params));

  router.get("/", async (request, response) => {
    // Handle GET request for rendering the form and the list of tasks.
    try {
      const tasks = await tasksService.getAllTasks();
      console.log("Tasks retrieved from service:", tasks);
      const completedTasks = await tasksService.getCompletedTasks();
      console.log(`Completed Tasks: ${JSON.stringify(completedTasks)}`);

      const error = null;
      const showSuccess = false;
      response.render("layout", {
        template: "index",
        tasks,
        error,
        showSuccess,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any unexpected errors.
      console.error(error);
      response.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });

  router.post("/add-task", async (request, response) => {
    // Handle POST request for form submission.
    const taskName = request.body.task;

    try {
      // Validation (step a and b)
      if (taskName.length < 3) {
        // Render error message for minimum task length.
        return response.render("layout", {
          template: "index",
          error: "Minimal length for task name is 3 letters!",
          tasks: await tasksService.getAllTasks(),
          showSuccess: false,
        });
      }

      if (await tasksService.taskExists(taskName)) {
        // Render error message for existing task.
        return response.render("layout", {
          template: "index",
          error: `Task "${taskName}" already exists!`,
          tasks: await tasksService.getAllTasks(),
          showSuccess: false,
        });
      }

      // Add the task to the tasks array (step c).
      await tasksService.addTask(taskName);
      console.log("Task added:", taskName);

      // Redirect back to the index page after processing the form data.
      const tasks = await tasksService.getAllTasks();
      console.log("Updated tasks array:", tasks);

      // Redirect the user back to the main page after adding a task.
      response.render("layout", {
        template: "index",
        tasks,
        error: null,
        showSuccess: true,
      });
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any unexpected errors.
      console.error(error);
      response.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
  router.post("/api/tasks/:taskName/done", async (request, response) => {
    const taskName = request.params.taskName;
    try {
      console.log(`Marking task "${taskName}" as done...`);
      await tasksService.markTaskAsDone(taskName);
      console.log(`Task "${taskName}" marked as done.`);
      response.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error marking task "${taskName}" as done:`, error);
      response.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });

  return router;
};
```

this is apiTasks route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const tasksService = require("../src/services/taskService");
const authenticateToken = require("../src/services/authMiddleware");

module.exports = (params) => {
  // Endpoint to add a new task
  router.post("/api/tasks", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const { title, description } = req.body;
    const email = req.user.email;

    try {
      // Add the new task to the user's TODO list
      await tasksService.addTask(email, title, description);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Task added successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to add task" });
    }
  });

  // Endpoint to get all tasks
  router.get("/api/tasks", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.user.email;

    try {
      // Get all tasks from the user's TODO list
      const tasks = await tasksService.getAllTasks(email);
      res.status(200).json(tasks);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to get tasks" });
    }
  });

  // Endpoint to get a specific task
  router.get("/api/tasks/:taskId", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.user.email;
    const taskId = req.params.taskId;

    try {
      // Get the specific task from the user's TODO list based on taskId
      const task = await tasksService.getTaskById(email, taskId);
      if (!task) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Task not found" });
      }

      res.status(200).json(task);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to get the task" });
    }
  });

  // Endpoint to update a task
  router.put("/api/tasks/:taskId", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.user.email;
    const taskId = req.params.taskId;
    const { title, description } = req.body;

    try {
      // Update the specific task in the user's TODO list based on taskId
      await tasksService.updateTask(email, taskId, title, description);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Task updated successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to update the task" });
    }
  });

  // Endpoint to delete a task
  router.delete("/api/tasks/:taskId", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.user.email;
    const taskId = req.params.taskId;

    try {
      // Delete the specific task from the user's TODO list based on taskId
      await tasksService.deleteTask(email, taskId);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Task deleted successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to delete the task" });
    }
  });
  return router;
};
```

and this is authenticationToken file

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const SECRET_KEY = "Secret Key";
const authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("authenticateToken middleware called");
  const token = req.header("Authorization");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ error: "Access denied" });

  jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error verifying token:", err.message);
      console.log(`token:${token}`);
      return res.status(403).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
    }

    // Debugging: Log the user data
    console.log("Decoded user data:", user);

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
module.exports = authenticateToken;
```

I tried debugging with console logs, I found out that authenticateToken middleware does not get called when I try to access api/tasks, I moved api/test endpoint to done route and it was same there also, but when I move this api/test endpoint in index route or in main.js it works when I test it with postman, also when I go to the localhost:3000 in my browser I can correctly access done route, page loads and works as it should. any help or advice would be appriciated.